# Can't delete records from table

Tags: mysql, innodb

```
CREATE TABLE `recipe` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ethnicityID` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `recipename` varchar(225) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `recipedescription` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `recipeprocedure` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `recipepremium` enum('YES','NO') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO',
  `recipeusercreator` enum('YES','NO') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO',
  `recipecreatorname` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `recipeapprovedby` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `recipeapproveddate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `recipestatus` enum('YES','NO') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO',
  `reciperequiresAdultSupervision` enum('YES','NO') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NO',
  `category_id` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `facebookID` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `recipetype` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(225) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `app` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `added_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `fbID` (`facebookID`),
  KEY `foreignkey_PerCategory` (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=19 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

This is my Table Syntax for a MySQL Table.

When I attempt to run this query

```
DELETE FROM `recipe` WHERE `ID` IN ('12','13','14','15','16','17','18');
```

I get the following error

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`desifoodapp`.`recipe_image`, CONSTRAINT `recipe_image_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`recipe_id`) REFERENCES `recipe` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I want to know how I can correct my table so that if a recipe is deleted, it's images are also deleted from the recipe_image table but the category that the recipe belongs to is not deleted. It's not affected.

recipe_image table below

```
CREATE TABLE `recipe_image` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recipeimage` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recipe_id` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `recipe_id` (`recipe_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `recipe_image_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`recipe_id`) REFERENCES `recipe` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

category table below

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoryname` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `categoryimage` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `facebookID` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `added_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just make it CASCADE for Deletion as well and try**

lets assume you have recipe table as Master, other tables are just liked on. 
when you make a foreign key constrain, just set them as CASCADE Delete and CASCADE update
so whenever you make changes in the master table, that is going to update all other tables as well. or if you delete one record in master table and will check all foreign key links and delete them on all client records as well

SET these lines in other tables definition

```
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

for instance : recipre_image

```
CONSTRAINT `recipe_image_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`recipe_id`) REFERENCES `recipe` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: Yeah use "alter table"

Comment: how can I fix the issue so it doesn't delete anything from the Category table? but does delete items from the Image table?

Comment: one way is link category table to master table, and image table to category table with cascade option only if possible. otherwise only master record deletion is possible

Comment: if you delete other branch tables one by one. yes you can delete whenever. no way protecting it

Comment: how do you make the category table the master?

Comment: you said that one way is to make it a master table. How do I make a Master Table?

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key constrain stops you from deleting things out of the table. You have to do a cascading delete or something similar:

[SQL Server: Deleting Rows with Foreign Key Constraints: Can Transactions override the constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740098/sql-server-deleting-rows-with-foreign-key-constraints-can-transactions-overrid)

Comment: Does this apply to MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make delete operation when `any field` in the table you are deleting has referred in another table as `foreign key` and the referenced table has any entry.

Instead you can use `cascade` delete operation to delete all records in your table and fields referenced tables. or you can use `rule` on the table you are going to delete

Refer the following link for cascade delete operation :
[Cascade Delete](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/)